# Unit Testing: Jasmine

Tags: javascript

`isTriangle` function checks the sides of the triangle and determines if the triangle is either a scalene, equilateral, or isosceles.

After writing the function, I need to do an unit test via Jasmine with Javascript.

Code:

```
function isTriangleTranslate(side1, side2, side3) {
    if (side1 === side2 && side3 === side2 && side2 === side1) {
        return ("It's an equilateral!");
    }
    if (side2 === side3 && side1 != side2 && side1 != side3 || side1 === side3 && side2 != side1 && side2 != side3 || side1 === side2 && side2 != side3) {
        return ("It's an isosceles!");
    }
    else {
        return ("It's a scalene!");
    }
}
```

Spec:

```
describe("isTriangle", function(){

  it("is an equilateral trinagle with three equal sides", function(){
    expect(isTriangleTranslate()).toEqual("It's an equilateral!");

  })

});

describe("isTriangle", function(){

  it("is an isosceles triangle with two equal sides", function(){
    expect(isTriangleTranslate()).toEqual("It's an isosceles!");

  })

});

describe("isTriangle", function(){

  it("is a scalene triangle with no equal sides", function(){
    expect(isTriangleTranslate()).toEqual("It's a scalene!");

  })

});
```

Errors are that the scalene & isosceles do not equal "It's an equilateral"

I do not want it to do that. I want it to determine if my side1, side2, & side3 are equal then it equals the string "It's an equilateral!"

If my side1, side2, & side3 have two sides that are equal the it equals the string "It's an isosceles!"

Else, the triangle is "It's a scalene!"

How will you write this in a unit test for Jasmine?

Comment: None of your tests pass *any* arguments to the function. What exactly did you expect?!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would simplify the function, just on general principles:

```
function isTriangleTranslate(a, b, c) {
   if (a === b && b === c && c === a) {
      return ("It's an equilateral!")
   } 
   else if (a+b == a+c || b+a == b+c || c+a == c+b) {
        return ("It's an isosceles!");
   } else {
        return ("It's a scalene!");
   }
}
```

Then, I would pass values into the test. You were just invoking the method with no arguments.

```
describe("isTriangle", function(){

  it("is an equilateral triangle with three equal sides", function(){
    expect(isTriangleTranslate(4,4,4)).toEqual("It's an equilateral!");
  })

});

describe("isTriangle", function(){

  it("is an isosceles triangle with two equal sides", function(){
    expect(isTriangleTranslate(4,4,5)).toEqual("It's an isosceles!");
  })

});

describe("isTriangle", function(){

  it("is a scalene triangle with no equal sides", function(){
    expect(isTriangleTranslate(4,5,6)).toEqual("It's a scalene!");
  })

});
```

Comment: `if (a == b == c) {` does that work for you? Because I didn't think it does, so I tested: `(2 == 2 == 2) => false` . I would say the better way to simplify it is to just remove the duplicate check of side1 and side2: `if (side1 === side2 && side2 === side3) {` should be enough.

Comment: Wait, it still isn't passing all the specs. Expected 'It's an isosceles!' to equal 'It's an equilateral!'. for the is an equilateral triangle with three equal side. I don't understand why it is doing that. Your thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind, it worked.  IceMetalPunk, you were right. Thank you both for your feedback on this! It has saved me a ton of time!

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Yes, that works for me in Chrome's console. enter ```let a=1, b=1, c=1;``` then enter ```a == b == c``` and you should see true. However, entering ```2 == 2 == 2``` in the console returns false. I don't know why that is, but we're working with variables not literal numbers.

Comment: @CliffHall It's not about variables or literals; it's because it only works if the value is 1. Any other number doesn't work. That's because 1==1==1 evaluates as 1 == (1 == 1) => 1 == true => true. Because true coerces to 1. But if the value is, for instance, 2, then 2 == 2 == 2 => 2 == (2 == 2) => 2 == true. True coerces to 1, and you have 2 == 1, which is false. It ONLY works if the values are all 1, by coincidence, but doesn't actually check what it should. It also won't work at all, even with 1, if you use strict equality (===) instead of loose (==) as the types are boolean and number.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk good catch. edited the answer to reflect that. Thanks.